# Opencv ip camera bad memory access exception using rtsp protocoll in Mat.inl.hpp header

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, rtsp, openvino

I'm trying to connect to a ip camera by rtsp protocoll to solve a object detection task, my issue is the access to the camera. I use the rtsp protocoll, and when I launch the system in release mode, after few minutes it gives me a bad memory access exception:

[image]

I access the camera using the following code:

```
VideoCapture cap; 
Mat src; 
cap.open("rtsp://<xxx>:<xxx>@ip_adress:554"); 

while(true){

    cap.copyTo(src);
    resize(src, src, Size(640, 480)); 
    imshow("source", src); 
    char k = (char)cv::waitKey(25);

    if (k == 27)
        break;
}
```

I process the frame to apply a neural network, and I don't figure why the system give me this exception, after 4/5 minutes.

Thank's.

Comment: Why do you resize every time in the loop? And for the code it would be better, if you provide full example with headers, so that we can know which function resize and imshow "links" to

Comment: I resize the frame every time because I capture with a resolution of 1920x1080. This aproach work fine when working with fixed camera, but I suppose the problem could be the latency of the ip camera that drops some frames when make the detections. Now while capturing and resizing the frames from the ip camera the system gives me this exception: !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Comment: Could you provide the call stack, when the error occurs?

Comment: The exception that occours is: [EXCEPTION] ImageWithFrameIdx::Read(): OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Comment: I'm using HikVision camera

Comment: Thank's for answer, but I've to work in c++. I try to build a multithread architecture, but this implementation gives me always a latency of ~3 seconds. Now I'm test to use LibVLC to process each frame.